# Merge xts objects of different size

Tags: r, merge, xts, quantmod

I want to merge different xts objects:

```
library("quantmod")
library("PerformanceAnalytics")
library("zoo")

ticks <- c("ABB","GEBN.VX","HOLN.VX")
starting.date<-as.Date("2012-01-01")
Data<-new.env()
getSymbols(ticks, env = Data, src = "yahoo", from = starting.date)
```

Next I want to calculate the returns using `eapply`

```
returns <- eapply(Data,dailyReturn,type="log")
```

This gives a list of `xts` objects. My goal is to merge these objects using merge:

```
merged.returns <- merge(returns)
```

I also tried the option `fill=NA`, `join="inner"` but I always get the same error message:

```
Error in data.frame(HOLN.VX = c(-0.00629152721948027, -0.0298954647966263,  : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 833, 824, 723, 849
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. We need to use `do.call`

```
do.call(merge,returns)
```

which solves the problem.